# How to pull values by reference number

Tags: r

I have a df of paired values and I want to be able to subset it by accessing only one value. This is my data:

```
df1 %>% head()
  values    pair_num
   <ch>     <int>
1  apple      1         
2  pb         1          
3  apple      2          
4  ranch      2          
5  apple      3          
6  sauce      3 
7  orange     4         
8  soda       4          
9  grape      5          
10 juice      5
```

So for example I would like to access all values associated with apple without knowing what they are and end up with something like this:

```
df1 %>% head()
  values    pair_num
   <ch>     <int>
1  apple      1         
2  pb         1          
3  apple      2          
4  ranch      2          
5  apple      3  
6  sauce      3
```

Comment: Why isn't row 6 `sauce` included, since it shares a pair_num with apple in row 5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the question, as I would have thought this would be the output (with row 6) that you'd want.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  filter(values == "apple") %>%
  select(pair_num) %>%
  left_join(df1)


Joining, by = "pair_num"
  pair_num values
1        1  apple
2        1     pb
3        2  apple
4        2  ranch
5        3  apple
6        3  sauce
```